# WordPress - Lock wait timeout exceeded - wp_cron

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Senhores,

Estou diante do seguinte log, mas não tenho conhecimento suficiente para entende-lo por completo. Como eu posso resolver tal problema ? Ele vem acontecendo constantemente, porém não sei como ele é gerado, tentei vasculhar as paginas do meu site mas não consigo reproduzir o erro.

```
[20-Jun-2017 21:02:38 UTC] Erro de banco de dados do WordPress Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction para a consulta INSERT INTO `wp_options` (`option_name`, `option_value`, `autoload`) VALUES ('_transient_doing_cron', '1497992508.0405650138854980468750', 'yes') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `option_name` = VALUES(`option_name`), `option_value` = VALUES(`option_value`), `autoload` = VALUES(`autoload`) feita por require('D:\home\site\wwwroot\wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('D:\home\site\wwwroot\wp-load.php'), require_once('D:\home\site\wwwroot\wp-config.php'), require_once('D:\home\site\wwwroot\wp-settings.php'), do_action('init'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, call_user_func_array, wp_cron, spawn_cron, set_transient, add_option
```

Uma parte do log que eu não entendi foi :

```
feita por require('D:\home\site\wwwroot\wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('D:\home\site\wwwroot\wp-load.php'), require_once('D:\home\site\wwwroot\wp-config.php'), require_once('D:\home\site\wwwroot\wp-settings.php'), do_action('init'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, call_user_func_array, wp_cron, spawn_cron, set_transient, add_option
```

Isso é um caminho ou são todos os lugares/funções que tiveram erro ?

Muito Obrigado.